# Multipolygons in GeoJSON file parsed with jsonlite are not visualized using leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I'd like to visualize some multipolygons in R using jsonlite and leaflet.
This was my initial code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(jsonlite)
library(geojsonlint)

url <- paste0("https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbsgebiedsindelingen/wfs?",
              "request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&",
              "typeName=cbsgebiedsindelingen:cbs_arrondissementsgebied_2019_gegeneraliseerd&",
              "outputFormat=application/json&srsName=EPSG:4326&propertyName=geom,statcode")
boundaries <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
geojson_validate(x = as.location(url))

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(boundaries)  %>%
  setView(5.387740, 52.155499, 7)
```

The GeoJSON file is valid. However, the multipolygons are not displayed on the map.

When I change my code using readr, they are displayed and everything looks fine:

```
library(readr)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(read_lines(url) %>% paste(collapse = "\n"))  %>%
  setView(5.387740, 52.155499, 7)
```

I'd like to add columns from another dataset to the feature data of the multipolygons in order to create a choropleth. So I really would like the first code chunk to work.

Why aren't the multipolygons displayed when I'm using jsonlite to read the GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code chunk the `features` array in the GeoJSON file is parsed as a list of length 11. In the second as a dataframe with 11 columns.
The solution seems to be:

```
boundaries <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url, simplifyVector = FALSE)
```